# Python file.read() function output?

Tags: python

I am trying to output a file's contents to terminal using the File.read() function in Python, but keep receiving the following output which doesn't match my ".txt" file contents.

**Python Code**

```
from sys import argv
script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read

current_file = open(input_file)
print "Print File contents:\n"
print_all(current_file)
current_file.close()
```

**Output:**

```
Print File contents:

<built-in method read of file object at 0x1004bd470>
```

Comment: you have answered your own question. you just said you are trying to do "File.read()" and yet in your code you do "File.read"

Comment: +1 to offset the (in my opinion) unjustified downvote. This is a legitimate question (a common mistake, especially if you come from a Ruby background where the parentheses are optional).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to *call* a function, you will need `()` after the name of the function (along with any required arguments)

Therefore, in your function `print_all` replace:

```
print f.read    # this prints out the object reference
```

with:

```
print f.read()  # this calls the function
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change

```
print f.read
```

to say

```
print f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a `read()`

```
current_file = open(input_file)
print "Print File contents:\n"
print_all(current_file.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the function in your `print_all` definition:

```
def print_all(f):
    print f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called the read method, you've just got it from the file class. In order to call it you have to put the braces. `f.read()`